# Java fastest way to get matching range

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, search, range

I have a set of integer ranges, which represent lower and upper bounds of classes. For example:

```
0..500 xsmall
500..1000 small
1000..1500 medium
1500..2500 large
```

In my case there can be over 500 classes. These classes do not overlap, but they can differ in size.

I can implement finding the matching range as a simple linear search through a list, for example

```
class Range
{
  int lower;
  int upper;
  String category;

  boolean contains(int val)
  {
    return lower <= val && val < upper;
  }
}

public String getMatchingCategory(int val)
{
   for (Range r : listOfRanges)
   {
      if (r.contains(val))
      {
         return r.category;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

However, this seems slow; as I need on average N/2 look-ups. If the classes were equally sized, I could use division. Is there a standard technique to find the correct range faster?

Comment: No, the ranges are given by the user, and do not need to be equally sized.

Comment: There is a construct called an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) which is designed exactly for storing/querying ranges. I don't know of a Java implementation but there might be one out there and in any case the logic is fairly simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `SortedMap` and its methods `tailMap` and `firstKey`. Check out the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) for full details.

The advantage of this approach over plain arrays is in the ease of maintaining your ranges: you can insert/remove new boundaries at any point with almost no runtime cost; with arrays it means copying both parallel arrays in full.

### Update

I've written code for both variants and benchmarked it:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public class BinarySearch
{
  static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 128, INCREMENT = 1000;
  static final int[] arrayK = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
  static final String[] arrayV = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
  static final SortedMap<Integer,String> map = new TreeMap<>();
  static {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arrayK.length; i++) {
      arrayK[i] = j; arrayV[i] = String.valueOf(j);
      map.put(j, String.valueOf(j));
      j += INCREMENT;
    }
  }
  final Random rnd = new Random();
  int rndInt;

  @Setup(Level.Invocation) public void nextInt() { 
    rndInt = rnd.nextInt((ARRAY_SIZE-1)*INCREMENT); 
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public String array() {
    final int i = Arrays.binarySearch(arrayK, rndInt);
    return arrayV[i >= 0? i : -(i+1)];
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public String sortedMap() {
    return map.tailMap(rndInt).values().iterator().next();
  }
}
```

Benchmark results:

```
Benchmark     Mode Thr    Cnt  Sec         Mean   Mean error    Units
array        thrpt   1      5    5       10.948        0.033 ops/usec
sortedMap    thrpt   1      5    5        5.752        0.070 ops/usec
```

Interpretation: array search is only twice as fast and this factor is quite stable across array sizes. In the presented code the array size is 1024 and the factor is 1.9. I've also tested with array size 128, where the factor is 2.05.

Comment: How would you create this map? I want to look up a single integer, and find the matching range. The SortedMap seems more targeted toward the other way around?

Comment: @RobAu: Putting there all the upper bounds should do. But this can never be as fast as a plain binary search.

Comment: @maaartinus But it's also doing a binary search through the tree. The difference is there, to be sure, but it's only by a constant factor, and not a large one at that. On the other hand, mutating the structure is O(logN) wheras with arrays it's O(N).

Comment: Agreed, there's only a constant overhead, but it might be huge: tree not perfectly balanced, indirection for nodes, indirection for wrapped ints, casts, object creation, whatever. I'd bet it's a factor 5 at least - do you care to benchmark?

Comment: Concerning mutations, I agree too, but again I'd bet that for up to 100 elements the arrays is faster. For huge sizes and whenever more flexibility is needed the tree wins.

Comment: @maaartinus I'd be interested to benchmark it if I catch time. Most of the stuff can be optimized well (indirections), but my main worry is the non-compact heap layout and CPU caches.

Comment: @maaartinus There, I've benchmarked it and the factor is 1.9 in favor of the array: 10.95 ops/µsec for array vs. 5.75 ops/µsec for map. Tested with Oracle jmh, array/map size: 1024. For array size 128 the ratio is much the same: 2.05.

Comment: I see I was wrong with my estimation. I managed to get a bigger ratio , however not big enough. I guess your benchmark has some non-negligible overhead, maybe `Random.nextInt(int)` as it needs division. See my answer.

Comment: @maaartinus `Random#nextInt()` calls are completely outside of measured times.

Comment: This makes sense, but then I don't know what's going on.

Comment: If you used `TreeMap`'s `ceilingEntry()`, you'll save creating new throwaway map and iterator. With this change, the SortedMap is only 1.6 times slower.

Comment: This is also captured in the `NavigableMap` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `Arrays.binarySearch` is your friend. Simply put all the boundaries in and handle the possible cases. Assuming you ranges leave no holes between them, you only need to put the upper bounds in.

For you example

```
0..500 xsmall
500..1000 small
1000..1500 medium
1500..2500 large
```

you'd use

```
int[] boundaries = {500, 1000, 1500, 2500};
```

and look up the input. Handle the two cases (found/not found) and you're done. Forget about ranges, they're nice but they don't fit you problem.

## Update

I also wrote a [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/RangeFindingBenchmark.java) and no matter how I try I'd lose my bet as the ratio is about 3 rather than 5. The strange things like `S001024` in my [results](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/e5c224d5-36f5-4d56-80ad-44c63e00bf90#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.parameters.size,scenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName) stand for the size 1024.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Even 'holes' could be covered like this, by defining them as a 'null'-category with boundaries that match the surrounding valid ranges.

Comment: Concerning holes: Sure. But I guess there should have no holes in a properly designed range system. Actually, I prefer to think about such things like: "if x smaller than 500 then xsmall else if x smaller than 1000 then small else if ... else xxxlarge" leaving no room for problems.

Comment: Note that Caliper's approach with `(int reps)` disturbs the measurement in strange and unpredictable ways as the loop gets unrolled and stuff hoisted out of it. `jmh` doesn't suffer from those issues and is overall a superior benchmarking tool to Caliper. [See this great talk by the author](http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/2630310904001).

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's really great! However, I'm not convinced. Loop unrolling is exactly what happens in the "real life". You just have to be careful that you don't do things which can be simplified, like e.g., summing up a constant. That's what happened in the video at 27:20. In my benchmark, I can't see anything like this, apart from folding the whole inner loop into `result += someConstant`, which is too hard for the JVM and obviously doesn't happen.